# How could I determine number of iterations untill convergence of iterative solvers in Math.NET?

Tags: math.net, mathnet-numerics

I am using last version of Math.NET.
I tried "residualStopCriterion._lastIteration" but it only works in debug mode since it's a non-public member. I need to save this values in a file.